# Use database already populated

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I need to use a database already populated and display its data in a list, I searched the internet and found the solution using a DB file and passing to SQLite, however, I am having difficulty importing the SQLite database from assents from android for my project, I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLnVhgYdVd8), but in my case it has this error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
```

### Code - DataBaseHelper

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String BD_NOME = "bdtestesqlite.db";
public static final String LOCAL = "/data/data/com.example.mts_rodrigues.myapplication/databases/";
private Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context, BD_NOME, null, 1 );
    this.mContext = context;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

}

public void abrirBD(){
    String pacote = mContext.getDatabasePath(BD_NOME).getPath();

    if(sqLiteDatabase != null && sqLiteDatabase.isOpen()){
        return;
    }

    sqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(pacote, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

public void fecharBD(){
    if(sqLiteDatabase != null){
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }
}

public List<Produtos> getListaProdutos(){
    Produtos p = null;
    List<Produtos> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    abrirBD();
    Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM bd_produtos", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        p = new Produtos(c.getInt(0), c.getString(1), c.getString(2),c.getString(3), c.getString(4));
        lista.add(p);
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    c.close();
    fecharBD();

    return lista;

 }
}
```

### Code - Main

```
private ListView lv;
private ListaAdapter adapter;
private List<Produtos> lista;
private DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

    dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    File data = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(DataBaseHelper.BD_NOME);
    if(false == data.exists()){
        dataBaseHelper.getListaProdutos();

        if(copiarBD(this)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Copiado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Erro ao copiar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }

    lista = dataBaseHelper.getListaProdutos();

    adapter = new ListaAdapter(this, lista);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private boolean copiarBD(Context context){
    try {

        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DataBaseHelper.BD_NOME);
        String outFile = DataBaseHelper.LOCAL + DataBaseHelper.BD_NOME;
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int legth = 0;
        while((legth = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0){
            outputStream.write(buff,0, legth);
        }

        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.v("Main", "Copiado");
        return true;

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

 } 
}
```

### Code - ListAdapter

```
private Context context;
private List<Produtos> lista_produtos;

public ListaAdapter(Context context, List<Produtos> lista_produtos) {
    this.context = context;
    this.lista_produtos = lista_produtos;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lista_produtos.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return lista_produtos.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return lista_produtos.get(i).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_lista,null);
    TextView nome = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_nome_produto);
    TextView categoria = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_categoria);
    TextView unidade = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_unidade);

    nome.setText(lista_produtos.get(i).getNome_completo());
    categoria.setText(lista_produtos.get(i).getCategoria());
    unidade.setText(lista_produtos.get(i).getUnidade());
    return v;
 }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of that code and [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to your project's `AndroidManifest.xml` file  if you are running your app on Android's Marshmallow or later version (API level 23 or greater)

Comment: Yes, I already added it to the project, but it still has not resolved